# How can I only return a part of my String method?

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, return

I have a String method that I would like to only return the part after the if statement but not the else! I have already tried a try & catch but didn't work either. Is that possible?

PS.This is my first time using stackoverflow.

```
String split() {
    String one = "", two = "";

        int index = tableFields.indexOf("(");
        if (index > 0){
        one = tableFields.substring(0, index);
        two = tableFields.substring(index + 1,
                tableFields.length() - 1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return "`" + one + "`" + " "+  two;
}
```

Comment: What is `tableFields` here?

Comment: `if` is not a loop :/

Comment: If the `else` should never happen, you should throw an Exception.

Comment: typically you will test will be `index > -1` though this should not matter unless table fields starts with "("

Comment: What do you actually WANT to have happen, if your String doesn't match the form "xxx(yyy)" ?

Comment: you could put an assert statement in (`assert false`) indicating that that shouldn't happen. then run the program with the `-ea` flag

Comment: @jcalfee314 - I think he/she is trying to implement something equivalent to `tableFields.replaceAll("^(.+)\((.+)\)$", "'$1' $2");` (with backquotes instead of quotes around `$1` but I can't work out how to get SO to escape them).

Comment: @DavidWallace I want it to return nothing, but at this moment that I made the changes above  it returns NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw an exception in the else, or return null.

Something like

```
else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Can't split");
}
```

or

```
else {
    return null;
}
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_builtin_exceptions.htm provides a list of some built-in exceptions that might be useful, otherwise you could write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can return both in the else and the if.

```
if (index > 0)
{
    one = tableFields.substring(0, index);
    two = tableFields.substring(index + 1, tableFields.length() - 1);
    return "`" + one + "`" + " "+  two;
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("error");
    return null;
}
```